# How is phone cable with iron called?

Tags: antenna-construction, wire-antenna

In in Russia I saw a phone cable called "field cable" (провод полевой П-274-М). It is a loosely twisted pair with some iron strains added alongside with copper ones.

[image: Field cable]
[image: Another field cable]

I tried to lookup something similar but I failed to find it.
I used phrases like "field cable" and "military cable" but got nothing like that.

Such cable is really good to make a wire antennas on trees because it has teflon-like surface and tolerant against harsh environment.

Comment: Perhaps it's this: http://everyspec.com/MIL-SPECS/MIL-SPECS-MIL-C/MIL-C-13294C_12128/ ?

Comment: I searched for "copper cable with steel strands" and did not find a clear English term for what you show. Instead that found something slightly different called "copperclad" where all the strands are copper-plated steel instead of a mix of strands. Similarly "reinforced stranded copper wire" didn't really turn up much either.

Comment: How wide are the two cables, including its insulation?

Comment: Looks like something similar but combining *aluminum* with steel is common for power transmission: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium-conductor_steel-reinforced_cable. Searching instead of "ACSR" to see if there was any analogous "CCSR cable" led to a maybe more common term "Aerial Services Wires" which "are supported by either an integral steel wire, glass fibers imbedded in the jacket, or by the use of high tensile copper-clad steel conductors."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is WD-1 or WD-1A military telephone line.

Lots of hams use it for [switchable-direction Beverage receiving antennas](https://web.archive.org/web/20181115070846/http://www.w0btu.com/Beverage_antennas.html), and with good results.

---

The steel strands provide extra tensile strength.

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this mostly off of web searches rather than industry experience but it looks like there's two potential terms for a related cable. At least related as to the general purpose — reinforcing conductive wires to better hold their own weight — if not exact construction/materials:

- Aerial Service Wire — i.e. wire used the delivery of a utility service is done via above-ground poles with the wires in the air. This term might be a bit more used in high-current AC power delivery, but I do also see it in relation to telephone/cables as well. E.g. http://www.newtechindustries.com/aerial-service-wire-asw-6-pair-22-awg-400-coil-adp-nms/
- Drop Cable — i.e. a conductor assembly used for the final "drop" (e.g. from a telephone pole down to a house) and seems to be a little more common for the communication industry rather than power companies. E.g. https://www.nordencommunication.com/en-in/product/telephone-drop-cable-no-1-2-6-and-8

Again, neither of my example links show the exact kind of wire you show but I think you were primarily wanting some ideas for what this sort of reinforced-for-hanging is called in general and I hope this helps!

Comment: Also, it appears that the iron (i.e. "steel") parts included more for reinforcement would be called the "messenger" strands or wires: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVofEtcL3Pw

Comment: Whether or not the lower cable is pole-to-house telephone drop cable depends on its size, which @zoonman hasn't yet answered. Also, it's stranded, and all the drop cable I've ever seen has solid conductors.